# Google Apps Marketplace App with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I would like to make a google chrome extension available through the Google Apps Marketplace.  As far as I can tell, the extension complies with all the rules, uses oauth correctly and so on.  But even though after an administrator enables our app we will have access to all the users in the account's oauth credentials and the individual users will see the app in the universal navigation menu, they won't have the extension installed for their browser.  Is the usual way to deal with this issue to use the link in the universal navigation menu to direct users without the extension to a page where they are directed to install the extension?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Google Apps Marketplace doesn't currently support the automatic installation of Chrome Extensions. Administrators can pre-install Chrome Extensions for their entire domain, but through a different process:

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1375694?hl=en